# GWT SimplePanel can only contain one child widget

Tags: gwt

Im trying to make a History Handler in my Project so i have a Login "page" and messure "page"

```
@Override
public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String token = null;

    String[] array1 = new String[3];
    if (event.getValue()!=null) {
        token = event.getValue().trim();
        array1=token.split("&",2);
    }

    if ((token == null) || (token.equals(""))){
        clearing();
        RootPanel.get("de").add(login, 457, 168);
    }
    else if (array1[0].equals("messure")){
        clearing();
        login.init(array1[1].substring(0, 2));
    }
    else{
        clearing();
        RootPanel.get("de").add(login, 457, 168);
    }
}
```

and here is the clearing:

```
    private void clearing(){

    RootPanel.get("en").clear();
    RootPanel.get("de").clear();
}
```

The Browser refreshbutton works well but when i try to go back and forward i get this:

> 10:37:56.831 [ERROR]  Uncaught exception escaped
>   com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: SimplePanel can only contain one child widget

its caused by a :
    commentBox.add(box);
commentBox is public static...

do i have to change it to a get/set methode to get it work or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exeception is telling you that you are adding more than one element into a SimplePanel

What is your commentBox ? Is it a simple panel ? Are you trying to add element more that once inside ?

Comment: public static DialogBox commentBox = new DialogBox();   in a Composite

Comment: Dialog box is a simple panel. You are probably calling add(wideget) on it multiple times. Probably because you dialog box is static.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a widget (for example, using a FlowPanel as a container for labels, text boxes, etc.), and then you add this widget to the DialogBox. DialogBox can only accept one widget as its body.